# how to share image and text in android

Tags: java, android

im created socail site and i want to share users post to external app

```
                    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                                    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Knackbe");
                                   // sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
                                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, AppPreferences.KEY_GET_APP_SHARE_TEXT + " " + "LInk" + mPostList.get(position));
                                    mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share via"));
```

Comment: Please notice that Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share image from your app first of all it must be store in your device and then you can share it.

Second use file provider for sharing items

Create a empty FileProvider class as mention

```
public class GenericFileProvider extends FileProvider {
}
```

Mention entry in android manifest as below inside application tag

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

Now create an xml file and name it as mention in manifest file "provider_paths" under res folder and create "xml" directory inside res folder and make provider_paths.xml inside it.

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

And Finally paste below code to your share button!

```
File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalCacheDir(),"wallyfy.png");
                        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,fOut);
                        fOut.flush();
                        fOut.close();
                        file.setReadable(true,false);
                        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,share);
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(ItemDescription.this,
                                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID +".provider",
                                file));
                        intent.setType("image/jpg");
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Share image via"));
```

Comment: harsh, where is the GenericFileProvider used?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
           sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
           sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Title");
           sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I challenge you to beat my score at Reveal.io. Get the app now and show your skills. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.terasoltechnologies.revealio");
           startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As @harsh mentioned in **Java**, we can use same way in **Kotlin**:

```
1- Add provider in Manifest file
2- Add filepaths in XML
3- Save Image , and Path of file
4- Share File
```

************** **SHARE** ***************

```
val imagePath = File(this.cacheDir, "images")
val newFile = File(imagePath, imageName)
val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.src.noveinway.fileprovider", newFile)
if (contentUri != null) {
    val shareIntent = Intent()
    shareIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) 
    shareIntent.type ="image/jpeg" 
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri)
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is a file for share")
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Choose app"))
```